# How to use paypal when the price is not fixed but generated in the previous page?

Tags: html, api, paypal

I have a page where a simple script calculates price after the user selects options but the problem is that I don't know how to take the generated price with the forms completed by the user and send that information to PayPal checkout page.

I made inputs that are hidden in the page that change values when user interacts with the page.

This is the page: http://lolo-boosting.ucoz.com/index/boosting/0-8

A working example here: https://boosteria.org/lol-elo-boosting

Would greatly appreciate if someone can share some links or information about this because I failed searching for this.

Comment: Just post the price so when it ends up on the paypal page you can get it $myPrice = $_POST['price'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [PayPal cart upload command method](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/).  That should allow you to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed.